# How do I turn off frame refresh for rendering

Tags: rendering

I'm still a novice to blender and 3D in general and I'm looking for something I don't know the name of. I remember about an option you can turn off that disable refreshing for each frame during render and creates an effect where it feels like every frame is rendered on top of each other. I can't find any info about it on the internet and I feel like I dreamt it.

Comment: There is no such thing as far as I know. It doesn't sound like a feature that would make much sense, to be honest. You can do whatever you like with your frames after you render so you can blend them to one, if you want.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I ended up rendering it as a sequence of .PNG and used After effect to create that affect. I remember seeing this effect in an Indy game so I'm sure I'm not crazy. Though I'm really not sure about it being possible in Blender. Thank you for your responses anyway :). Here's the result, eventually it might make my post clearer. https://i.imgur.com/Z0QNjtV.png

Comment: Sure it is possible in Blender, it's just not a feature. You can do all kinds of compositing with Compositor nodes.